# Install Eclipse for C/C++ in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Error/Crash on Run

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu

I am attempting to install Eclipse for C/C++ manually since the version included in the Ubuntu Software center appears to be for Java development only.  I complete the steps include in the guide linked below.  However when I attempt to launch I receive the below error:

```
XYZ@ubuntu:~/Downloads$ sudo eclipse
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Ignoring option MaxPermSize; support was removed in 8.0
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.BaseStorage (file:/opt/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.osgi_3.6.2.R36x_v20110210.jar) to method java.net.URLClassLoader.addURL(java.net.URL)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.BaseStorage
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
```

After this warning is displayed Eclipse fails to launch.

Below is the error log entry in Eclipse:

```
!SESSION 2020-05-07 22:53:03.283 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=M20110210-1200
java.version=11.0.7
java.vendor=Ubuntu
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.linuxtools.product
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.linuxtools.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator 4 0 2020-05-07 22:53:03.668
!MESSAGE
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: The bundle "org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator_1.0.200.v20100503 [1]" could not be resolved. Reason: Missing Constraint: Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironm>
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.getResolverError(AbstractBundle.java:1317)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.getResolutionFailureException(AbstractBundle.java:1301)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:319)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:374)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1067)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:561)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:546)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:459)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:440)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:227)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:337)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2020-05-07 22:53:03.672
!MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator_1.0.200.v20100503.jar/ was not resolved.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2020-05-07 22:53:03.679
!MESSAGE The following is a complete list of bundles which are not resolved, see the prior log entry for the root cause if it exists:
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2020-05-07 22:53:03.679
!MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator_1.0.200.v20100503 [1] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator 2 0 2020-05-07 22:53:03.679
!MESSAGE Missing Constraint: Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: CDC-1.1/Foundation-1.1,J2SE-1.4

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2020-05-07 22:53:03.680
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to acquire application service. Ensure that the org.eclipse.core.runtime bundle is resolved and started (see config.ini).
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:74)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:369)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:620)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:575)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1408)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1384)
```

Unfortunately I am both unfamiliar with Java and have had little success in finding a solution online.  Any help would be greatly appreciate.

Guide I used:
https://linuxconfig.org/eclipse-ide-for-c-c-developers-installation-on-ubuntu-20-04

Comment: These are warnings, not errors, all about compatibility between Eclipse and modern JDKs, so only Eclipse team should care about.

Comment: Unfortunately Eclipse immediately crashes after displaying these warning (apologies I have just edited my original post to state this).

Comment: Eclipse does not require root account to run, do you have some specific case to do so ( i see 'sudo' ) ?

Comment: No.  I tried both with and without sudo with the exact same result (I just happened to append the code when I tried with sudo)

Comment: looks like you're trying to use very outdated version of Eclipse: org.eclipse.osgi_3.6.2.R36x_v20110210.jar , but i have org.eclipse.osgi_3.15.200.v20200214-1600.jar

Comment: I actually downloaded this directly from the Eclipse website.  I used the download specific for C/C++ developers (https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/helios/sr2/eclipse-ide-cc-linux-developers-includes-incubating-components).  I had originally tried the main Eclipse downloader (20-03) but also no luck.  Is there a better link or guide as compared to the one I followed?

Comment: I managed to get the 20-03 to work.  Was a permissions issue with the download.  So not really solving the original issue but Eclipse is running so all is good.  Than you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In a round-about way I managed to find a solution to my problem.  I retried the 20-03 installer from Eclipse and managed to get that version to finally install correctly using the below guide:

https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=316457

Answer (score 0):

To install Eclipse on Widows/Ubuntu, We always use the following, and that works very well.
1.firstly, install or unzip JRE.
2.create a directory for Eclipse, 
eg. 'D:\myEclipse' on Widows, '~/myEclipse/' on Linux.
3.download target Eclipse from official web to the directory above.
4.extract Eclipse file in the directory.
5.open eclipse.ini, add the following on '-vmargs' to indicate JRE path.
-vm
(path of the JRE you unzipped)/bin/
same way for both Windows/Linux

Our projects written by C/C++/Java, one project one directory, clear and easy! This is our way, for your reference!